# batch script for mysqldump everyday

Tags: mysql

I am new to scripting where I am using MySQLdump  everyday to retrieve yesterdays data from external server.I don't want to mention date it should pick yesterdays date automatically and need to schedule it every time.

```
  mysqldump -P 3310 -h XXX.XXX.0.XXX -u [root] -p[kiran] customer1_ pay_and_display --where = 
ticket_datetime > '2013-12-09' and ticket_datetime < = '2013-12-10'> mybackup.sql
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option is:

```sh
mysqldump -P 3310 -h XXX.XXX.0.XXX -u [root] -p[kiran] `customer1_` `pay_and_display` --where="DATE(`ticket_datetime`) > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY AND DATE(`ticket_datetime`) <= CURDATE()" > mybackup.sql
```

You can simplify the condition with something like:

```sh
mysqldump -P 3310 -h XXX.XXX.0.XXX -u [root] -p[kiran] `customer1_` `pay_and_display` --where="DATE(`ticket_datetime`) = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY" > mybackup.sql
```

Comment: No problem, second note: I bet he wants `>= ...and <` instead of `> ... and <=`

Comment: @fancyPants: Good recommendation for preethi.

Comment: @preethi: The `WHERE` seems to be working properly according to the following [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d92bb/1). What other information can give us to help you?

Answer (score 2):

Use curdate() and INTERVAL x DAY

```
mysqldump -P 3310 -h XXX.XXX.0.XXX -u [root] -p[kiran] customer1_ pay_and_display --where = ticket_datetime > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY and ticket_datetime < = CURDATE() > mybackup.sql
```

Comment: I dont know why my where condition is not working if i use mysqldump it  is working fine but not with where condition

Comment: `mysqldump -P 3310 -h XXX.XXX.0.XXX -u [root] -p[kiran] customer1_ pay_and_display`- this works fine ... but not the where conditon.